# document.scripts is not equal to document.getElementsByTagName("script")

Tags: javascript, html, dom, htmlcollection

`document.scripts` returns an `HTMLCollection` object holding a list of all scripts in a document. Similarly, `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` returns another `HTMLCollection` object holding a list of all scripts in the document.

I expected the following statement to be true however it's not.

```
document.scripts === document.getElementsByTagName("script") // false
```

What is the reason for both these not being equal?

Comment: While both of them should return the same HTMLCollection, I think the ways those collections are filled are not the same. In other words, `document.scripts` is not an alias for `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` op. Weird why though, the definition in standard seems to make those equivalent. Perhaps that's the matter of being a legacy?

Comment: I just spotted another quirk of JavaScript...

Comment: I don't even expect two calls to `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` would compare equal, well it turns out equal in my browser :O

Comment: do you have some reference that they should be the same instance?

Comment: @appleapple exactly, even I tried two calls to `document.getElementsByTagName("script")`, and they turned out the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example where they give different results. document.scripts returns the set of *HTMLElement* scripts, where getElementsByTagName("script") returns the set of all scriot elements regardless of namespace.

(The StackSnippets logic adds two script elements to the document beyond those shown in the example code here.)

```js
console.log('There are ' + document.scripts.length + ' document.scripts elements');
console.log('There are ' + document.getElementsByTagName("script").length + ' document.getElementsByTagName("script") elements');
```

```html
<script>console.log('foo');</script>
<svg><script>console.log('bar');</script></svg>
```

Comment: This means that `document.scripts` and `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` indeed represent two different collections. It's just that in most cases, they turn out to be the same.. Is this it?

Comment: They turn out to have the same contents, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I wasn't able to find the theoretical reasoning here, but it seems that in some cases those might not be strictly equivalent, and implementations have to bear that in mind. For example, in Chromium the implementations are different, and the real funny fact is that both are *cached* collections:

```
// renderer/core/dom/document.cc
HTMLCollection* Document::scripts() {
  return EnsureCachedCollection<HTMLCollection>(kDocScripts);
}

// renderer/core/dom/container_node.cc
HTMLCollection* ContainerNode::getElementsByTagName(
    const AtomicString& qualified_name) {
  DCHECK(!qualified_name.IsNull());

  if (GetDocument().IsHTMLDocument()) {
    return EnsureCachedCollection<HTMLTagCollection>(kHTMLTagCollectionType,
                                                     qualified_name);
  }
  return EnsureCachedCollection<TagCollection>(kTagCollectionType,
                                               qualified_name);
}
```

It's not just `scripts`: all the document HTMLCollection properties (forms, applets, images etc.) are wrapped into `EnsureCachedCollection<HTMLCollection>`.

For tags, however, it's `EnsureCachedCollection<HTMLTagCollection>`. While HTMLTagCollection is a child of TagCollection (which in turn is a child of HTMLCollection), those are different caches.

Now the way I expect caches to work, the same requests should give the same result... unless you hit different caches. In this case, same result means not  just equality of values, but equivalence of objects.

That's why you get strict equivalence between both subsequent calls to `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` and subsequent calls to `document.scripts` - but not across those.

UPDATE: Check @Alohci answer, it gives a good example of when the results will actually be different by value for those requests.

Comment: so, basically, it's just about js rules

Comment: Again, by the code alone it's more about the difference between different implementations of DOM: remember, HTML is not the only thing that's covered by that. But to be honest, I'm not really sure how `document.scripts` can be a `TagCollection`, for example... in WWW, legacy is really dark matter. )